# Imagenes de the_content() no se ajustan al máximo de columna (Wordpress y Bootstrap)

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap, wordpress

Tengo un problema, ya que al tener texto e imagenes en entradas o páginas de wordpress, estas no se ajustan al 100% del ancho de la página que deberían, sino que se ajustan al máximo de la misma imagen, generalmente mayor al de la página, y a su vez no son responsive.

Esto ocurre solo en el contenido de the_content()

```
<div class="contenido">
  <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?> <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8" id="contenido" align="justify">
            <?php the_content() ?>
        <div class="fb-comments" data-href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" data-width="100%" data-numposts="5"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4 d-none d-lg-block" id="single-sidebar">
          <?php get_sidebar( 'primary' ); ?>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?> <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
```

He probado con ajustar el width="100%" pero no funciona, sin embargo es solo en the_content() ya que las imágenes, por ejemplo, "destacadas" en cada entrada,  incluyen la clase ***img-fluid*** (Está basada en Bootstrap).

¿Alguna forma de que puedan tener el ancho de la columna como máximo y sean responsive?

Answer (score 0):

Es problema de css más que de wordpress. Lo que necesitas es añadir una regla css en la hoja de estilos del tema:

```
img{
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Espero que se solucione tu problema.

Comment: Me sirvió en otra página, era lo más logico de hacer, sin embargo acá no me funciona, me sigue marcando más ancho que la columna...

Answer (score -1):

SOLUCIONADO. El problema era que la clase div donde estaba el contenido, estaba dentro del main, donde tenía que ajustar el CSS, finalmente ya está funcionando bien.

Comment: Y que hiciste exactamente para solucionarlo?